# Relationship between User - calendar Many to many or one to Many

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm, one-to-many

I have an application that needs to store calendar events for each user. One user can have many calendar events and One user can be an attendee to Many calendar events. Which I have created as below:

User:
Id
name
.....

Calendar
Id
description
start_date
....
CreatedBy -> userID in user table
Attendee -> userId in user table

My question does this effected table normalization. Would it be better to separate into a third table? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand completely what you are trying to do with

> CreatedBy -> userID in user table Attendee -> userId in user table

Correct me if my model is wrong: [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed4vn.jpg)

If you do that, it would not be possible for a user to be an attendee on many events. One user could have many events but could only be one attendee.

So that would be the point where you need a third table because it doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: no you are right with your model only the attendee is in the calendar table. I see your point suppose a third table would be needed. I have the same issue with user feedback as each user can have and can leave many reviews. Trying to work out the best data model for that

Comment: @Jes if the attendee is in the calendar table, an event can only have one attendee. The only way would be to store the attendee data as an array (text) in the attendee column. Something like: [1,3,4,7,10] (user ids). But then you are not using the correct normalization. If you want to follow the third normal form you have to use a third table like [this](https://prnt.sc/9AjJKZNxJ_rV)

Comment: Thank you for this much appreciated. I was wondering if i should take this approach or not. Each event will only have one attendee but even then a third table is a cleaner approach thanks. This approach would be best for reviews?

Comment: @Jes Ah okay, now I understand. If you have only one attendee you should not use a third table. Then you have not a N to M relation. Use a third table only then. The problem on relations is that they often need a join. A join meens also performance. So you should use as less joins as possible without disregarding the normalization forms. I'm working in a company that had so many table entries (a way more than 1 billion), that joins took too long so they used text based arrays. So its very complex but for your project you should use all normalization forms.

Comment: yes, I was trying to avoid joins as I have enough tables in my database already don't want it getting unmanageable as you said. I will stick to two and use 3 for the reviews as it's a many-to-many relationship. Thanks again